# Lighttpd mod_rewrite to Apache mod_rewrite

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, lighttpd

I want to turn this Lighttpd mod_rewrite to apache rewrite code.

```
$HTTP["host"] =~ "^(i\.ylar\.se|puush\.me)$" {
    server.document-root = "/var/www/servers/i.ylar.se/"
    url.rewrite-once = (
            "^/api/up" => "/upload.php",
            "^/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$" => "/view.php?image=$1"
    )
}
```

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need more than just a rewrite here...

Something like this might do it:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName   i.ylar.se
    ServerAlias  puush.me

    DocumentRoot /var/www/servers/i.ylar.se

    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteRule ^/api/up               /upload.php [L]
    RewriteRule ^/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$     /view.php?image=$1

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: It seems like the VirtualHost part giving me the Error 500 Internal Server Error.

I will check with my webhost if vhost is allowed/active?

Comment: Now I see, I can't edit the vhost settings myself..

Comment: So you can't edit your server config? You're limited to what you can put in a .htaccess file? In that case you can add the rewriterules, but you can't define virtualhosts.

Comment: I contacted the support and got the answer that I could do it in the control panel. But the rewrite stuff doesn't seem to work.

Comment: IF the rewrite doesn't work the first thing to do is to enable rewritelog. That way you'll see what goes on. You are putting the in a .htaccess file? If so you probably want rules that don't start with /.

Comment: Yes, I'm using htaccess. I will try without the slashes.